# Error 404 while connecting to cordapp using rpc

Tags: spring-boot, block, rpc, blockchain, corda

I am trying to make a simple Cordapp and trying to connect to it using rpc via a Spring Boot application. Both Cordapp and Spring Boot applications are working fine without any errors but while making the request via postman it shows, ***error 404***. I dont know what I am doing wrong. Can someone help me with this?

My application.properties file for Spring Boot app:

```
server.contextPath=/Chubb-Insurance

server.port=7090

node.PartyA.rpc.hostport=localhost:50004

db.connection=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:2005/node
nodename=insurer
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG


cron.expression=0 0 0 01 * ?

debit.point.qry.gt.200=100
debit.point.qry.gt.30
```

My Controller:

[image]

My build.graddle file for the cordapp:

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
directory "./build/nodes"
node {
    name "O=Notary,L=London,C=GB"
    notary = [validating: true]
    rpcSettings {
        address("localhost:10008")
        adminAddress("localhost:10048")
    }
    p2pPort 10006
    cordapps = ["$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
}
node {
    name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
    p2pPort 10007
    rpcSettings {
        address("localhost:50004")
        adminAddress("localhost:50005")
    }
    //webPort 10009
    h2Port 59001
    cordapps = ["$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
    rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
}
node {
    name "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"
    p2pPort 10010
    rpcSettings {
        address("localhost:50006")
        adminAddress("localhost:50007")
    }
    //webPort 10012
    h2Port 59002
    cordapps = ["$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
    rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
}
node {
    name "O=PartyC,L=Sydney,C=AU"
    p2pPort 10013
    rpcSettings {
        address("localhost:50008")
        adminAddress("localhost:50009")
    }
    // webPort 10015
    h2Port 59003
    cordapps = ["$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
    rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
}


}
```

Comment: What URL are you visiting to get the 404 error? A 404 means "Not Found". If it was a CorDapp problem, you'd expect a 500 error code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not added your own cordapps to the `cordapps` property of the nodes in the `build.gradle`. Add them there and it should work.

Comment: My cordapp is working fine i guess. The main problem is connecting it to Spring boot app via rpc

Comment: so you definitely added your cordapp? Im pretty sure if it fails with failure to connect to rpc it should output an error in the log file for you saying that is the reason why. Does your rpc connection look something like this? ```init {
        val rpcAddress = NetworkHostAndPort(host, rpcPort)
        val rpcClient = CordaRPCClient(rpcAddress)
        rpcConnection = rpcClient.start(username, password)
        proxy = rpcConnection.proxy
    }```

Comment: No its not showing any logs on the Cordapp side. It is just showing 404 while I am trying to make the request to the api exposed by Spring Boot

Comment: There are no logs in the Spring app instead a warning is generated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52146450/warning-starting-the-spring-boot-application

Comment: Looking at the code from that link I agree with the answer to it. Just use `@Controller`, use `@RestController` if possible.

Comment: Even after removing that and using @RestController I am getting the same warning.

Comment: I find the provider warnt unlikely if you have removed it and recompiled properly