# Warning starting the spring boot application

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to write a SpringBoot application. But when I am trying to access it using Postman, it shows Status as 404 and gives a warning on console:

> WARN 6616 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.g.jersey.internal.inject.Providers
>   : A provider com.cognizant.insurance.controller.RestServiceController
>   registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider
>   interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint
>   configuration problems the provider
>   com.cognizant.insurance.controller.RestServiceController will be
>   ignored.

My Rest Controller is:

```
@Component
@Provider

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/api", produces="application/json")
public class RestServiceController {
    @Autowired
    private CordaRPCService cordaRPCService;
    @Value(value = "${node.PartyA.rpc.hostport}")
    private String nodeRpcHostAndPort;
    @Value(value = "${nodename}")
    private String nodeName;

    CordaRPCOps rpcService = null;

    String inDateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";

    PolicyState policy;

    @RequestMapping(value="/createpolicy", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String doTradeCreditPolicy() {

    return "Hello";

}
```

My project Structure:

[image]

Main File:

```
package com.cognizant.insurance;



@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableCaching
@ComponentScan("com.cognizant.insurance")

 public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(final String[] args) {

    new Application()
    .configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class))
    .run(args);
}
```

}

Comment: Your code suggests that you use a Spring `RestController` for the endpoint, but the warning suggest that you also have a Jersey server instantiated at runtime. What is the story with Jersey? Either way, the warning is not related to the 404 you get when invoking the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any special reason for you to use `@Provider` annotation? If not, try to remove it. Controller should work without this annotation.

The same is about `@Component`. 
This is a general-purpose stereotype annotation indicating that the class is a spring component. If you are using `@Controller`, you don't need this annotation.

You can read about differences between `@Component` and `@Controller` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in).

Comment: Even after removing both of them. I am still getting the same warning.

Comment: Can you provide your pom.xml/gradle build file?
Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37204930/rest-filter-registered-in-server-runtime-does-not-implement-any-provider-inter